# printing dynamically string in one line in python

Tags: python, command-line, printing, line

I'm trying to print strings in one line.

I've found solutions but they don't works with windows correctly.

I have text file contains names and I want to print them like this

`name=john` then change john to next name and keep `name=`, I've made this code but didn't work correctly with windows:

```
op = open('names.txt','r')
print 'name=',
for i in op.readlines():
    print '\r'+i.strip('\n')
```

thank you for your time

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to _overwrite_ part of the line, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using '\b' as suggested by senderle

```
import sys
import time

sys.stdout.write('name=')
last_lenght = 0
with open('names.txt') as names:
    for name in names:
        sys.stdout.write('\b' * last_lenght)    # go back
        sys.stdout.write(' ' * last_lenght)     # clear last name
        sys.stdout.write('\b' * last_lenght)    # reposition
        sys.stdout.write(name.strip())
        sys.stdout.flush()
        last_lenght = len(name.strip())
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply using `\r` won't work in this case, because that returns you to the beginning of the line, so you'll have to reprint the entire line. Also, in some systems (including Windows, I think) Python's `print` statement (function in 3+) interprets `\r` as a newline. I believe this code *should* be system-independent.

```
import sys, time

with open('names.txt', 'r') as names:
    prev_len = 0
    for name in names:
        sys.stdout.write('\r' + ' ' * prev_len)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        output_string = '\rname={}'.format(name.strip())
        prev_len = len(output_string)
        sys.stdout.write(output_string)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.3)
print
```

You could also use `\b`, which generally moves the cursor back by one space.

As you pointed out, it's necessary to overwrite the previously printed line with spaces, which means it's necessary to remember the length of the previous line. It makes sense to encapsulate that state in an object, I think. Here's a much cleaner solution than the above that uses that strategy:

```
import sys, time

class LineUpdater(object):
    def __init__(self, outfile=None):
        self.prev_len = 0
        self.outfile = sys.stdout if outfile is None else outfile

    def write(self, line):
        line = line.strip()
        output = '\r{:<{width}}'.format(line, width=self.prev_len)
        self.prev_len = len(line)
        self.outfile.write(output)
        self.outfile.flush()

with open('names.txt', 'r') as names:
    out = LineUpdater()
    for name in names:
        out.write('name={}'.format(name))
        time.sleep(0.3)
    print
```

Comment: sir your code doesn't works correctly with windows ,, the issue is if you printing  long name for example `naaaaaaaaaaaaame` then next name would be `john` the output would be like  `johnaaaaaaaaaame`
i've tried your solutions before i post this problem  and didn't work with windows

Comment: Ah! Of course -- `\r` is usually used to print lines of equal length. This wouldn't work on any system for your purposes! I'll update.

Comment: @EngHamoud, see my edit. The new code should work correctly. There may be a better way to do it, but it works at least!

Comment: yes it works thank you verrrry much ,, but really its little bit kludge , thank you anyways i'll try to find out more appropriate way

Comment: @EngHamoud, see my most recent edit for what I think is the cleanest solution.